# The server tag is not well formed (img tag)

Tags: html, asp.net

This is an error, I know this can be solved by looking at that tag and correcting that. But I am stuck with this little

```
<img runat="server" ID="Level1<%# Eval("LinkID") %>" class="imgClass" 
     alt="" src="../../../Styles/expand-large-silver-Shapes4FREE.png" height="11px"  
     onclick="meClick(this.id)" />
```

where I mistaken, Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using `<%# "Level1"+Eval("LinkID") %>'`

Combining

```
<img runat="server" ID='<%# "Level1"+Eval("LinkID") %>' class="imgClass" 
     alt="" src="../../../Styles/expand-large-silver-Shapes4FREE.png" height="11px"  
     onclick="meClick(this.id)" />
```

Comment: Now this error "The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />"

Comment: yes, the trick is to use ' (apostroph) whereever you use inline coding.

Comment: @DND I am not sure about the dynamic ID will it except or not.